# Basic Input Output Program to read from local datasheet

Tags: input, output

i'm a coding newbie and i'm having trouble with coding, and would love some help.

Writing in Python 3 by the way.

Basically, the user will input a name (like John Smith), if John Smith belongs to "list R", then the program will print ("John Smith belongs to Company R")

I don't know what these kinds of programs are called, so I couldn't really find it off google.

EDIT: made some progress but get this error when I enter a second name

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    Frank
NameError: name 'Frank' is not defined

I think my code only runs once, and after completion it doesn't return to val = input

```
R = ["James", "John"]
val = input("Enter Name: ")
if val in R:
    print (val, "is from company R")
else:
    print (val, "is not from company R")
```

I've

Many thanks!

Comment: What language are you writing in, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm writing in Python, and honestly, i'm back to square 1 with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could enclose your code in a while loop to return to val = input("Enter Name: ") until a blank value is entered.

```
R = ["James", "John"]
val = input("Enter Name: ")
while val != "":
    if val in R:
        print (val, "is from company R")
    else:
        print (val, "is not from company R")
    val = input("Enter Name: ")
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!